# How to write from Dataproc to BigQuery across multiple datasets and date partitions?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataproc

We have a daily Dataproc process that imports data from several sources for analysis on behalf of our customers. Currently we don't receive a huge amount of data daily, but expect it to ramp up considerably. Our current process has four Dataproc Spark jobs that import, parse, join, and output to Cloud SQL in the final job, writing temporary Avro files between each job. Even with our current level of data Cloud SQL is starting to strain a little (partly due to an admittedly poor schema). We want to move to BigQuery, so my first cut is to have a fifth job that reads the final Avro file and outputs to BigQuery, basically paralleling the current Cloud SQL output job.

Using the example at [Using the BigQuery Connector with Spark](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example) I have worked out how to do this, but require a bit more complexity. Specifically I need to:

- Separate individual customer data (multiple customers' data can arrive from a single source) into individual datasets
- Partition the data by day based on a "DateOfService" field

The only way I see to do this is to create separate RDDs by customer and DateOfService and write them individually to the appropriate dataset and table partition. My concern with this is that the writing seems to take a VERY long time (several minutes) for a single RDD and if I have to write several separate ones it will likely become prohibitive.

Here is the salient part of my code so far. The rest is just all the configuration which is identical to Google's example except with my table schema and project's values.

```
// Read the processed data from Avro
val claimsRdd = sc.hadoopFile[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]]("gs://path/to/avro/file")

// Convert from a RDD[Row] to RDD[String]. Conveniently these are JSON strings.
val claimsJson = claimsRdd.map(l => new String(l._1.datum.toString()))

// Convert into a RDD[(Null, JsonObject)]
val claimsJsonObj = claimsJson.map(s => (null, (new JsonParser).parse(s).getAsJsonObject))

// Write to BigQuery
claimsJsonObj.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf)
```

My questions are:

1. Is this multiple RDD approach I described the only or best way to
   do this?
2. Is there a faster way to write to BigQuery from Dataproc? Or is
   Dataflow faster in this regard? I may be able to rewrite to
   Dataflow, but I have a parser written in Scala I would have to
   rewrite to Java, and we make use of Spark's SQL capabilities and
   working out how to do that in Dataflow seems a bit daunting. But if
   that's the better way I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Batch Dataflow doesn't currently support writing to a dynamic set of BigQuery tables, so you'd need to know the set of customers and days up front.  However, if that is the case, Dataflow will handle this efficiently and do the uploads in parallel.

Additionally, it's possible to use Scala code directly in a Dataflow pipeline; just use the Dataflow API from your Scala program.

I don't know much about Spark, so can't comment on the best way to handle this there.